# How can I stop having to type "$scope" before every variable and function in my Angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's really annoying to have to type $scope before any of the fields or methods I use. I feel like I'm doing something wrong. I've seen some people use methods instead of controllers and use this, but I really would like something like:

```
use($scope) {
    var one = 'test';
    var two = function(v) { return v * 2 };
    two(one);
}
```

instead of:

```
$scope.one = 'test';
$scope.two = function(v) { return v * 2 };
$scope.two($scope.one);
```

Maybe I just don't get how to write code the angular way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is the second way that you posted, as it's the way that most programmers are familiar with, and doesn't lead to any weird edge cases.

In JavaScript you can technically use a `with` statement to define a scope for subsequent commands, though according to MDN it is not recommended since it can cause bugs and compatibility issues.

**WARNING:** USE OF THE `WITH` STATEMENT IN JAVASCRIPT IS NOT RECOMMENDED. The following example is for completeness only:

```
var a, x, y;
var r = 10;

with (Math) {
  a = PI * r * r;
  x = r * cos(PI);
  y = r * sin(PI / 2);
}
```

More info on the `with` statement [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: That MDN source states this: `Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.` Which basically means: Don't use with, it's bad. Also it [considerably slows down](https://jsperf.com/with-statement/1) the executed code.

Comment: @Dodekeract That recommendation from MDN is actually the first sentence of my answer, but thank you for the performance insight!

Comment: @MaximilianLaumeister oh, didn't see that

Comment: no offense to the author of this answer, but this is **definitely not** accepted practice in angular, and though it may be "what the OP was looking for", it's really a bad idea to have an accepted answer like this associated with the angular tag, giving others in the future any suggestion that this is acceptable code within use of the angular framework.

Comment: You should never use the with statement in javascript. This is a dreadful answer.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I haven't seen you in the JS room in a while

Answer (score 4):

If you're using $scope purely to bind variables to your view, then you should look into [controllerAs](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax. When you use controller as, a controller that looks like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Some title';
});
```

would instead look like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function () {
  this.title = 'Some title';
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but Max's answer was what I was looking for. However, I'm going to start using the controllerAs syntax from now on, so thank you!